# TYPO3 copy part of a page tree to another server

Tags: export, typo3

I have two TYPO3 9.5.22 installations [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and playground.mysite.com. playground.mysite.com is basically a snapshot copy of [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). Each site sits on its own server. Both sites have seen changes.

Now I want to copy a specific page subtree from playground.mysite.com to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). So far I've played with the export tool, but this tells me that all there is a LOST RELATION for each and every file – mostly images.

When running the export I get an XML file that seems to contain the page structure and the textual content but not the images.

Is there a clean and easy way to copy a page subtree from one server to another together with all images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can configure the options of the export, which tables are considered, which pages, which relations are included. even the size of files to include. but if you take to much it might not work.
at least in the past mostly the import was more often a problem than the export.
you need a lot of memory on the servers to handlethe big data structure of a page tree with all dependent records (including files)

for a smooth handling so much pages I often split the export in smaller chunks which need proper restoring on the target system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with some help of someone else from the community I managed to create an export file. I needed 4GB of memory to create a 65M XML file with 15 pages and a few images for each page. I agree, the import seems to be the real consumer of memory. I could only export and import a chunk of one page. After that all the links from this page to the other pages are broken. Maybe I go the brute force route and temporarily  assign 100GB of memory to the VM my site runs on and see what happens :-)